# Running two django sites from one docker container?

Tags: django, docker

I have a website that uses the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework) to basically have two different domains serving the same Django project. In production, this is served through a Docker container (including an nginx server). What I would ideally do is have both sites be served from one single Docker container. Is this possible? The websites share the same database so that would be no problem, but what I am not able to figure out is how I can add another "web" instance to the same docker container using the same port (likely impossible). Are there other ways?

Spinning up two docker containers on the same server would also be fine, but again I'd have to use the same ports which causes conflicts.

FYI here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'  

services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    expose:
      - 80
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
```

Comment: Why not play with the configs of your applications and change their ports and then expose the custom ports ?

Comment: Well the issue is that they should both be available as regular websites, so they both need to be served on port 80...

Comment: What do you think about providing these two different applications on port 80 and 8080 + using https://traefik.io/? 

Publish a gateway with different urls (https://localhost/one + https://localhost/two) which forward internally to port 80 and 8080?

Comment: @LennartBlom Thanks, I will have a look. But it would definitely add a layer of complexity. If I can avoid having to do something like that then I'd love to know.

Comment: Yup, sure thing. Avoid complexity if you can! But two applications on the same port sounds a little bit wrong from my point of view. Correct me, if I am wrong! :)

Comment: Run 2 containers with Django listening on port 80 for ex. in their respective containers. Map host ports 8081 and 8082 to containers port 80 respectively. Configure nginx to listen on port 80 and have two server blocks to redirect it to either of the domain names using <nginxIP:8081> and <nginxIP:8082> based on the server name in server block

Comment: Thanks @ben5556 that sounds like a doable approach. I will try to roll this out. Feel free to post as an answer to accept.

Comment: Sure. You can also configure nginx with two server blocks redirecting to containers directly using upstream directive

Answer (score 2):

Run 2 containers with Django listening on port 80 for ex. in their respective containers. Map host ports 8081 and 8082 to containers port 80 respectively. Configure nginx to listen on port 80 and have two server blocks to redirect it to either of the domain names using  and  based on the server name in server block. OR configure nginx with two server blocks redirecting to respective containers directly using upstream directive.